# Include 'RunningMode' in CloudFormation template to deploy AWS Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am currently working on a proof of concept which also covers the deployment of AWS Workspaces using CloudFormation. Therefore, I'd like to add the RunningMode (Either 'AutoStop' or 'AlwaysOn') as parameter. So far I was not able to figure out how to include this into the CloudFormation template. Any ideas?

Cheers, Dominik

Current template (Simplified):

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "UserName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "test_user"
    }
  },
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "TestWorkspace1": {
      "Type": "AWS::WorkSpaces::Workspace",
      "Properties": {
        "BundleId": "<BUNDLE_ID>",
        "DirectoryId": "<DIRECTORY_ID>",
        "UserName": {
          "Ref": "UserName"
        },
        "RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled": false,
        "UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "Username": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            {
              "Ref": "UserName"
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "Description": "Workspaces Username"
    },
    "StaticMessage": {
      "Value": "In case of first usage, you will receive a initial password for the Amazon Workspaces Client separately, once the workspace has been created.",
      "Description": "Workspaces note"
    }
  }
}
```

[Question in AWS-Forum (Duplicate)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269539&tstart=0)

Comment: Looks like API Documentation doesnt show that option, however in boto3 I can see a property for it.. http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/workspaces.html
Worth trying it on CF - try adding under properties 'WorkspaceProperties': {
                'RunningMode': 'AUTO_STOP'|'ALWAYS_ON',
                'RunningModeAutoStopTimeoutInMinutes': 123
            }
Maybe its just not documented?

Comment: This was also my first approach. Unfortunately it returned "Encountered unsupported property WorkspacesProperties".

Alternatively, we consider to use the AWS Java SDK, which provides an API to access AWS Workspaces. It's working that way, though we'd prefer using CloudFormation.

- Dominik

Comment: Unfortunately looks like it’s unsupported, open a feature request and implement a workaround such as using the API in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discoverd, that you can now specify the values for

RunningMode:
RunningModeAutoStopTimeoutInMinutes:

in Cloudformation Templates.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-workspaces-workspace-workspaceproperties.html